# Presenting a Popover From a Rect Problem

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a UITableViewCell that has some labels and images that can be clicked. I want to present a popover whenever a user clicks on any part of the cell. How can I achieve this without interfering with the click actions of the labels & images?

I am currently creating an invisible button ontop of some other clickable items in the cell and calling the popover:

```
    [replyPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(77, 25, 408, 68) inView:self permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

Unfortunately, because the button is on top of the labels & images I am unable to click them.

**How can I show a popover by clicking on the background of a cell, so that there is no interference when clicking images & labels inside the cell?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add my popover code in the tableview delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```